# Restrict Binomial/Factorial to non-analytically continued versions

Tags: special-functions

I like to use the (common) representations of the binomials for integer arguments, such that eg `Binomial[1/2,1]` evaluates to `0` rand not to `1/2`. Is there a simple generic way to do this?

This is relevant since there are quite some standard expressions and equations which are based on that, e.g. definition of Fibonacci Polynomials, ...

Comment: In version 11.3., `Binomial[1/2, 1]` _does_ evaluate to `1/2`. If your version does not support this, you might define `binomial[n_, m_] := Gamma[n + 1]/(Gamma[m + 1] Gamma[n - m + 1])`.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher: I also get 1/2 but I need a simple way to get to 0.

Comment: Ah, now I got it (hopefully...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
ClearAll[binomial]
binomial[
   n_?(Statistics`Library`RealIntegerQ[#] && Positive[#] &),
   m_?(Statistics`Library`RealIntegerQ[#] && Positive[#] &)
  ] := Binomial[Round[n], Round[m]];
binomial[n_, m_] := 0;
```

**Older, less robust version**

```
ClearAll[binomial]
binomial[
   n_Integer?Positive,
   m_Integer?Positive
  ] := Binomial[n,m];
binomial[n_, m_] := 0;
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot!!

Comment: See also last edit. The old version did not behave as desired for negative arguments and for integers in disguise (such as `binomial[2.,1]` also returned `0`). Just tell me if you happen to observe bugs.

Comment: Well, actually what I was looking for was anyway the version for natural numbers, and it was easy to understand. Thus, would it be possible that you still give the old answer as an alternative?